# Deformation of a diagram preserve the homotopy limit

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, model-categories, infinity-categories, homotopy-limits

I have been a bit sloppy in the title, but let me be specific. I stepped again into the subtle difference between homotopy limit and limit in the homotopy category, in the following version.

Suppose you have two diagrams of spaces $X_{\bullet}, Y_{\bullet}$ and a homotopy equivalence $f_i : X_i \to Y_i $ such that for any morphism $i\to j$, the morphisms $Y(i\to j)\circ f_i$ and $f_j\circ X(i\to j): X_i\to Y_j$ are homotopic. Is it true that $\text{holim} X_{\bullet} \simeq \text{holim} Y_{\bullet} $ ?

My favorite diagram is $\Delta$, i.e. cosimplicial objects, but I suspect the result should not depend on this. Let me remark that if the $f_i$ would commute strictly the result would be true.

**Bonus question.** If the answer is "No, they can be different", are there a higher compatibility constraints one can impose so that it becomes true? For example, by specifying what the homotopy $f_{ij}$ between $Y(i \to j) f_i $ and $f_j X(i \to j)$ should respect, and then bla bla..

**Remark**. I suspect that a "not so higher" version should be true for the following reason. If I have a cosimplicial object, I take the chain complex pointwise, and I apply the Dold-Kan correspondence, I get a bicomplex $C_*(X_\bullet)$: the horizontal differential is the differential of chains, while the vertical differential is the alternated sum of the cosimplicial (co)faces.
I have tried to apply the definition of multicomplex homotopy equivalence between $C_*(X_{\bullet})$ and $C_*(Y_{\bullet})$, but there a few more maps to find and I don't want to mess with so many equations. In particular I should find an homotopy inverse to $f$. I hope that the "not so high" is low enough that one homotopy suffices, without higher constraints.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is false.

Consider the two $C_2$-spaces $S^{2\sigma}$ and $S^2$, where $\sigma$ is the sign representation and $S^V$ denotes the one-point compactification. Then the two underlying spaces are the same and the action looks trivial in the homotopy category. However, the homotopy fixed points differ. (After 2-completion, these look like the same as the actual fixed points- by the Sullivan conjecture- and the fixed points in $S^{2\sigma}$ are $S^0$ which is different than $S^2$.)

The `higher' version would amount to unwinding the definition of a morphism in the $\infty$-category $\mathsf{Fun}(K, \mathcal{C})$ (if you have such a morphism, and it is pointwise an equivalence, then the diagrams are equivalent and hence give equivalent homotopy limits). In the case $\mathcal{C}=\mathsf{Spaces}$, this goes back a ways to work of Dwyer and Kan (see, e.g., their [paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2045321?seq=1) "Realizing diagrams in the homotopy category by means of diagrams of simplicial sets.")

In the case of cosimplicial objects in stable $\infty$-categories, we can do better. By the $\infty$-categorical Dold-Kan correspondence, the $\infty$-category of cosimplicial objects is equivalent to the $\infty$-category of cofiltered objects. If $X$ and $Y$ are cofiltered objects, then it really is true that the two diagrams are equivalent you can build equivalences $f_i$ from $X(i)$ to $Y(i)$ making the diagrams commute up to homotopy. This is because the poset $\mathbb{N}$ can be built as a coequalizer of two maps from $\coprod [1]$ to $\coprod [0]$, so it's easy to build maps out of $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Thank you for the really complete answer! Would you mind providing a reference for the last part? That is, if I have two (strict) cosimplicial objects in a stable infinity category, and a pointwise equivalence between them that makes the diagram commute up to homotopy, then the homotopy limits are the same. Infact, I am interested in the spectral sequence on chains $C_*(X_{\bullet})$, and your statement would imply the spectral sequences are the same (or at least they converge to the same thing).

Comment: I think I forgot to tag: @DylanWilson.

Answer (score 5):

Let me try to complement Dylan Wilson's great answer with an example which is easier to analyze at the point-set level.

Take $I = B\mathbb N^2$, so that a functor $I\to\mathcal S$ is a space $X$ together with two commuting endomorphisms $\alpha_{0},\alpha_1:X\to X$. An explicit model for the homotopy limit is the space of tuples $(x,\gamma_i,\Gamma)$, where $x\in X$ is a point, $\gamma_i$ is a path from $x$ to $\alpha_i(x)$, and $\Gamma:[0,1]^2\to X$ is a square with sides $\gamma_0,\alpha_0\circ\gamma_1,-\alpha_1\circ\gamma_0,-\gamma_1$.

For the counterexample, set $X = S^1\times\mathbb R, \alpha_0(z,t) = (z,t+1),\alpha_1(z,t) = (e^{2\pi i t}z,t)$; one can check that for any choice of $(x,\gamma_i)$ the winding number of the concatenation of the four paths $\gamma_i$ and $\alpha_i\circ\gamma_{1-i}$ is $1$, so that the square $\Gamma$ can't exist, i.e. the homotopy limit is empty.
Then set $Y = S^1$ with both endomorphisms the identity; since the limit of this diagram is nonempty, so is the homotopy limit (in fact, one easily computes the homotopy limit as $S^1\times \mathbb Z^2$); in particular the homotopy limits of $X$ and $Y$ are not homotopyequivalent. The homotopy equivalence $f$ is the projection to the first factor, and the required homotopy between $(z,t)\mapsto z$ and $(z,t)\mapsto e^{2\pi i t}z$ is conctructed by rescaling the second variable.

The reason that this counterexample works is that $X$ is a point-set model for the $\infty$-functor $B\mathbb N^2\to \mathcal S$ which sends the point to $S^1$ and the morphisms to the identity, but fills the resulting commutative square with a nontrivial self-homotopy of the identity of $S^1$.

Comment: Thank you Bertram! This is a very nice example and I will undoubtedly recycle it for geometric examples of homotopy limits :)) It is also clear from your last sentence how the higher things get into play. However, I think I'll accept Dylan answer because it has references to the cosimplicial part, which I am more interested in. Best!